# Thread Safe Circular Queue Implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

template <typename T> class RingBuffer {
public:

    explicit RingBuffer(std::size_t capactiy) : _buffer_capacity(capactiy){
        std::unique_ptr <T[], RingBufferFree> buffer_ptr(new T[capactiy]);
        _ring_buffer_array = std::move(buffer_ptr);
    }

    ~RingBuffer() {

    }

    void Push(T val) {
        while (!TryPush(val));
    }

    T Pop() {
        T val;
        while (!TryPop(&val));
        return val;
    }

private:

    //Private Struct to ensure allocated memory is freed.
    struct RingBufferFree{
        void operator()(T * ring_buffer_memory) { delete[] ring_buffer_memory; }
    };

    //Private Member Functions
    bool TryPush(T & val) {
        const std::size_t current_write = write_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t current_read = read_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t next_write = increment_index(current_write);

        if (next_write == current_read) { return false; }

        _ring_buffer_array[current_write] = val;
        write_position.store(next_write, std::memory_order_release);

        return true;
    }

    bool TryPop(T * val) {
        const std::size_t current_write = write_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t current_read = read_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (current_read == current_write) { return false; }

        *val = _ring_buffer_array[current_read];

        const std::size_t next_read = increment_index(current_read);
        read_position.store(next_read, std::memory_order_release);

        return true;
    }

    std::size_t increment_index(std::size_t index) {
        return (index + 1) % _buffer_capacity;
    }

    //Private Member Variables
    std::atomic<std::size_t> read_position = 0;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> write_position = 0;

    std::size_t _buffer_capacity;
    std::unique_ptr<T[], RingBufferFree> _ring_buffer_array;
};
```

I have tested my code and it appears to work, but I would like some second opinions on what I did. This first time I have tried lock free programming with atomic variables and so I would appreciate it if I had more experienced programmers provide feed back.

Answer (score 2):

First some style notes:

- `capactiy` should be `capacity`. Spelling is important in all kinds of writing, because all writing is primarily *communication*, intended for humans just as much as for computers.
- The entire `RingBufferFree` widget is unnecessary. `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` will [do the right thing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) by default.
- Temporary variables are often a code smell, if they're not serving an explanatory purpose. In the constructor, `buffer_ptr` is unnecessary.

  ```
  explicit RingBuffer(std::size_t capacity) :
      _buffer_capacity(capacity),
      _ring_buffer_array(new T[capacity])
  {}
  ```
- Personally, I'd never write `std::size_t`, since `size_t` works just as well; but your mileage may vary.
- `~RingBuffer() {}` is unnecessary; remove it.
- It's unclear to me why you're using a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` at all, when a `std::vector<T>` would work just as well.
- It's odd that `TryPush` takes `T& val`, instead of `const T& val` or (better) `T val` or (perhaps best in this context) `T&& val` — where you [move-assign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/1424877) either of the last two into place with `_ring_buffer_array[current_write] = std::move(val);`.
- Likewise, in `TryPop` you probably ought to be moving-from the buffer element: `*val = std::move(_ring_buffer_array[current_read]);`

Okay, let's go find some concurrency bugs!

---

Obviously you'll have problems if two different threads try to call `Push` at the same time (because one will overwrite the other's pushed item); and you'll have problems if two different threads try to call `Pop` at the same time (because both could pop the same item).

So let's assume that this is just supposed to be a single-producer single-consumer queue, and look for bugs in that scenario.

---

Actually, assuming it's only supposed to be single-producer single-consumer, it's pretty clean! The only potential issue I see is that if the user calls `Q.Pop()` on an empty queue, or `Q.Push(x)` on a full one, then the thread in question will [busy-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) forever — or at least until some other thread manages to break in and get some actual work done. It would be significantly friendlier if you put something in the `while` loop's body, e.g. [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) — or even better, just `return false` or `throw QueueEmptyException()` or something like that, so that the *calling code* can decide what it wants to do, instead of getting blocked for an indefinite amount of time.

In other words, `TryPush` and `TryPop` smell like the real primitive operations here; `Push` and `Pop` are non-primitive operations of dubious utility.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the `TryPush` fix. So I have the `Push` method call `TryPush`so are you saying I leave the function signature of `Push` the way it is and convert `TryPush` to this `TryPush(T && val)`? Because doing so causes the code to fail compiling and with the error **'bool RingBuffer<int>::TryPush(T &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'**

Comment: @ChrisOgle: Yep, you've got it. Read up on [C++ move semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics/11540204#11540204); I don't think it's plausible to teach the whole topic in a CodeReview answer, let alone a CodeReview comment. ;)